# what's wrong with this jquery dialog focus function?

Tags: jquery, dialog, focus

If someone can help me with this, I will be eternally grateful.

Essentially, the focus function is supposed to make it so that if the user presses enter in any but the last of the 3 fields in the dialog, it acts as a tab. If they press enter in the LAST field it submits the form. The latter function works but the tabbing does NOT.

Anyone know why?. I didn't post the whole block of code but this should give enough data. Am I using event.target wrong?

```
$('#dialog-add-items').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width:500,
        position:['center',80],
        modal: true,
        focus: function() {
            $(':input:last', this).unbind('keyup').keyup(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').click();
                }
            });
            $(':input:not(:last)', this).unbind('keyup').keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    name=event.target;
                    $(name).next('input').focus();
                }
            });
        },...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say that `$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').click();` is the culprit. Try giving your button an ID and reference like that:

```
$('#dialog-add-items').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width:500,
        position:['center',80],
        modal: true,
        focus: function() {
            $(':input:last', this).unbind('keyup').keyup(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $('#okbutton').click();
                }
            });
            $(':input:not(:last)', this).unbind('keyup').keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    name=event.target;
                    $(name).next('input').focus();
                }
            });
        },
        buttons: [{text: 'Ok', id:'okbutton'}],...
```

Comment: didn't work. i hope it was clear that it the second part that's not working, i.e.:

 $(':input:not(:last)', this).unbind('keyup').keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    name=event.target;
                    $(name).next('input').focus();
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

I simply ended up adding an if/else statement to test which of the 2 fields were focused and then jumping to the next one. cumbersome and ugly but it was the only thing i could get to work.